# Jquery Datatable edit/delete icons

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I want to add 2 extra columns (edit and delete) in my datatable.
each row in my datatable contains a hidden columns which is the record ID, so when users click on edit or delete i would like to get selected row Id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var mytable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
                "fixedHeader": {
                    "header": true,
                    "footer": true
                },

                "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]],

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Users/Prov",
                    "type": "Get",
                    "data": { "id": "@userId", "cityId": "@cityId" },
                    "datatype": "json"

                },

                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": -1,
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": "<button>Delete!</button>"
                    }
                ],

                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id", "visible": false, "searchable": false },
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "City" },
                    { "data': "Code" },
                    { "data': "Title" },
                ]


            });

            $('#userTable tbody').on('click', 'button', function() {
                var rowData = mytable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
                alert(rowData[1] + "'s City is: " + rowData[2]);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to add another column with edit hyperlink by specifying a new column in columns array property of datatables and then pass the id to the edit action via query string like:

```
"columns": [
                { "data": "Id", "visible": false, "searchable": false },
                { "data": "Name" },
                { "data": "City" },
                { "data": "Code" },
                { "data": "Title" },
                {
                            "title": "Edit",
                            "data": "Id",
                            "searchable": false,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                return '<a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Users")?id=' + data + '" class="editUser">Edit</a>';
               }
           ]
```

it will call the edit controller with the id passed as parameter, and your edit action would be like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     // do the business logic here 
}
```

The same way you can add details and delete button as well.